# What does the term 'Lazy State Definitions' mean in reference to $stateChangeNotFound

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm watching a video on [ui-router](https://youtu.be/lBqiZSemrqg?t=42m53s) and the speaker (Tim Kindberg) mentioned that `$stateChangeNotFound` is good for lazy state definitions. What does he mean by that and in what context would it be used?

I'm assuming it's associated with the term Lazy Loading which I do understand. New to AngularJS/ui-router and appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lazy loading refers to loading code at runtime, just-in-time.  In this context, it means potentially creating/defining the state only when a user tries to navigate to the state (that doesn't yet exist).

For example:

- These states exist because they've been declared at config time

  1. `a: { url: '/a' }`
  2. `b: { url: '/b' }`
- User clicks a link to `/c`.
- `$stateNotFound` event is fired on root scope
- application listens to `$stateNotFound` event
- application loads state definition (from server, etc) for a new state `c: { url: '/c' }`
- once the state definition is lazy loaded, the application then manually re-triggers ui-router to sync the url '/c', and ui-router routes to the now-newly-created state `c`.

Have a look at [UI-Router Extras Future States](http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/#/future) for an implementation of this pattern.

Comment: Awesome, super clear response thank you. What is the benefit of creating it on the fly instead of declaring that state within the routes?

Comment: Depending on how large the app is, lazy loading may improve performance by loading only what is necessary . You might also swap available states at runtime based on permissions.